# Exception in application start method error. I am using JavaFX in IntellJ

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

So When I was writing my code, I was trying to run my code.
Here is the error message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root hasn't been set. Use method setRoot() before load.
/Users/anish/IdeaProjects/FBLA2020CompetitionCode/out/production/FBLA2020CompetitionCode/sample/HOME.fxml:17

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2621)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$RootElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1338)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application sample.Main
```

and here is my code for my Main.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("HOME.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 380, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and here is my code to my FXML file:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: #081B33;" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="260.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2F4562;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="179.0" fitWidth="266.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                    <Image url="@../images/Flag-color.png" />
                </ImageView>
                <Button fx:id="homeButton" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="260.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2f4562;" text="The Hub" textFill="WHITE">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../images/icons8_Home_32px.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="studentButton" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#HandleButtonAction" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="260.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2F4562;" text="Student" textFill="WHITE">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../images/icons8_Person_32px.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="editButton" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="260.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2f4562;" text="Edit" textFill="WHITE">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../images/icons8_Slider__32px.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="printButton" alignment="BASELINE_LEFT" graphicTextGap="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="260.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2F4562;" text="Print" textFill="WHITE">
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="23.0" fitWidth="27.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@../images/icons8_Open_Envelope_32px.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="50.0" />
                    </padding>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </VBox>
        <Label layoutX="292.0" layoutY="27.0" text="FBLA Community Service" textFill="WHITE">
            <font>
                <Font name="System Font" size="24.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="292.0" layoutY="75.0" prefHeight="92.0" prefWidth="650.0" spacing="50.0">
            <children>
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="92.0" prefWidth="125.0">
                    <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="N/A" textFill="#de0000">
                            <font>
                                <Font name="System Bold" size="26.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="Total Hours" textFill="WHITE" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
                <Label />
                <Label />
                <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="92.0" prefWidth="125.0">
                    <children>
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="88.0" text="N/A" textFill="#de0000">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="26.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="129.0" text="Most Hours Worked" textFill="WHITE" />
                    </children>
                </VBox>
            </children>
            <padding>
                <Insets left="5.0" />
            </padding>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT" layoutX="292.0" layoutY="174.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2F4562;">
            <children>
                <Label alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="Search:" textFill="WHITE">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                    </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="13.0" />
               </font>
                </Label>
                <TextField alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="157.0" promptText="search students">
                    <padding>
                        <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
                    </padding>
                </TextField>
            <Region prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="250.0" />
                <Button fx:id="print1Button" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="164.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2F4562 #2F4562;" text="Print" textFill="WHITE">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                    </font></Button>
            </children></HBox>
        <VBox fx:id="pnitems" layoutX="292.0" layoutY="227.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="650.0">
            <children>
                <TableView style="-fx-background-color: #081b33;">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Student" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Grade" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Hours" />
                        <TableColumn minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Awards" />
                    </columns>
                    <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                    </columnResizePolicy>
                </TableView>
            </children></VBox>
        <Label layoutX="292.0" layoutY="6.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="148.0" text="Error: N/A" textFill="#e80909" />
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

I'm confused on what is happening, I tried multiple solutions on the web but nothing worked. I tried to configure my VM to add more heap, that didn't work. I tried to add a .module, but that gave me a weird error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the tag `fx:root` and replace it with `AnchorPane` :

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="1000.0" style="-fx-background-color: #081B33;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <children>
        <VBox prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="260.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2F4562;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                ...
```

Or if you use SceneBuilder, go to Controller tab and uncheck "Use fx:root construct" :

[image]

**edit** : don't mind the controller path in the screenshot, just uncheck the box as I said.